# Is there a way to search ALL Disqus comments for a particular search term through their API

Tags: php, disqus

I've been researching for the past few hours and I still don't know if there's a way to search through Disqus comments on any website for common terms through their api. Like searching twitter hashtags. In there [public api data](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1131785-available-public-api-data) page where you can return a Post's message, I see no mention of Disqus-wide API search capabilities. I would be using PHP if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use most post list endpoints in the Disqus API. See the 'query' parameter here: https://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/

However, you're limited to one or two words at most in a query, because the endpoint is traditionally prone to timing out. The search also isn't highly sophisticated, so you might not get as many results as you'd like - but it may work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such possibility with the Disqus API. You can search for a particular search term but only if you specify a forum or thread to look in. There is no global search by term in any forum or thread.

For example:

```
http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/lists.json?api_key='.urlencode($key).'&query='.$query;
```

,where `$query` will be your search term, it returns a http 400 Bad Request Error. The error message is:

**Missing required argument: 'forum' or 'thread'.**

So when you include in your API call the argument `query` you have to include also a forum or a thread.

Read more for the documentation [**here**](https://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/)